# Go back to reset local commit

Tags: git, commit, reset

I cloned a repository, made some changes and committed a few files, then used `git pull` to fetch remote modifications. Realizing it had automerged some changes, I wanted to go back to my latest (local) commit, to just `git fetch` remote and merge manually.

So, I used `git log` to find my latest commit, and `git reset --hard my_commit_hash`. But now, I’m back at square one, with every single one of my commits lost. How can I go back to my latest one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you actually made commits, and somehow went to a commit that was not actually your latest, then you can use the reflog to get back to where you were.  But it sounds more like you added files with `git add` and didn't actually `git commit` them.  In which case, your problem is much harder.  Added files will have created objects in your object database which you can find with `git fsck`, but restoring them requires a little more work than you would otherwise need.  So which situation are you in?

**edit:**

Once you see the commit you want in the reflog, say for instance `HEAD@{3}`, all you have to do is `git reset --hard HEAD@{3}`